# Identifying if an app exists, if not go to play store

Tags: android

a bit of a doozy.

What I would like to know is that is it possible that if an app doesnt exist on a device, can it go into the play store to download it. I know I need to put this code in

```
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
    startActivity(i);
```

But if that doesnt exist, can I then get it to go to the Play Store

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use one of the following function to check whether the app is installed or not.

**Function 1**

```
private boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean installed = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        installed = false;
    }
    return installed;
}
```

Or **Function 2**

```
public boolean isAppInstalled(String targetPackage){
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();        
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(targetPackage)) return true;
    }        
    return false;
}
```

**USAGE**

```
if(isAppInstalled("com.package.name")){
    //Your Code
}
else{
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.package.name")));
}
```

Comment: where you have put packageName, would that be replaced with com.package.adress ?

Comment: Yes. `com.package.name` should be replaced by `com.package.address`